# Next Without For Error, If Else Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code to automatically update a scorecard sheet according to some conditions. 
Set to Green if date is past today, and status is requested
Set to Gray if date is past today and status is anything else
Set to Red if date is anything before today

Already tried running a conditional if else and the code is shown below. Keep getting a compile error saying "Next Without For" although both are included in the code below

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 to Last_Row

    If Cells(i,Phase).Value = "3" Then
    If Cells(i,PSEDate).Value > Date Then
    If Cells(i,P3S).Value = "Requested" Then
    Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Green"

    Else
    Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Gray"
    End If
    Else
    Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Red"
    End if

    Next i
```

Comment: You have three instances of `If` but only two `End If`, and you're using the multiline style of `If`. Indentation would help.

Comment: Indeed. Indent your code and the problem shows up like a flag.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one more `Else...End If` clause here:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 to Last_Row

    If Cells(i,Phase).Value = "3" Then
      If Cells(i,PSEDate).Value > Date Then
        If Cells(i,P3S).Value = "Requested" Then
          Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Green"

        Else
           Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Gray"
       End If
      Else
        Cells(i,RAG).Value = "Red"
      End if
    //Missing one more Else...End If clause here...

    Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your help! Have an awesome day

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BigBen you are missing one "End If" statement. Also try to work with indents to spot such erros.

```
Dim i As Integer
With Sheet1
For i = 7 To 17
'First condition
  If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "3" Then

    'Second condition  
    If .Cells(i, 2).Value > Date Then

      'Third condition
      If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Requested" Then
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = "Green"
      Else
        .Cells(i, 4).Value = "Gray"
      'Third condition end
      End If

    Else
      .Cells(i, 4).Value = "Red"

    'Second condition end
    End If

  'First condition end
  End If       

Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! Pretty new to VBA and coding so I really appreciate the tip about formatting. Have a nice day